# ul auto indents as well as only pads one side?

Tags: html, css

I know there have been many questions about ul auto indents, I've tried with no success many of those answers and I have the additional problem of when adding a container with padding, it seems to only pad one side.

Basically I'm trying to get a ul bar fixed to the bottom of the window. This bar is inside a container (main) to give it padding from either side of the window). It is designed to auto expand with the width of the window (liquidish) so there is no defined width beyond the initial width=device width.

When written by itself, I get a small auto indention on the left side of the ul. I've tried adding 0 padding and margins to the ul and li elements and that seems to have no effect as well as others. When I add in the container it seems to pad only the side with the indent problem. I'm sure its something simple and stupid, but I appreciate any help.

As an aside.. the width of the li elements being 33.3% is due to using a spacing box hack found on stackoverflow. The use of it doesn't change/help/hurt anything in this problem, so I omitted it to keep this a little more simple.

JSFiddle Link http://jsfiddle.net/XdHXf/1/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #455868;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #455868;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: The padding is coming from the div that contains the `ul`

Comment: Agree with @ExplosionPills. the `1 em`

Comment: As I mentioned, the div just adds to the problem. I probably should have left it out.
http://jsfiddle.net/XdHXf/2/
You can still see a small indent to the left of the ul that I cannot get rid of. Shouldn't the padding also affect both sides where in this case its only affecting the 'problem' (left) side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the browser's builtin stylesheet. If you add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

the small extra space goes away.

As an alternative, you get similar results, when you check `Normalized CSS` under `Fiddle Options`.

Comment: This fixed it both in fiddle and in practice of course. Thank you good sir, greatly appreciate it. (Edit: I will Upvote you and such as soon as I gain enough reputation for it. Thank you again.)